# Fusion 2 - blank screen - no start button

Tags: macbook, vmware-fusion

I have Fusion 2 on my MacBook. It was working fine until this morning. Logged on and it took too long to log my personal settings to load. I shut it down. Shut down the MacBook and restarted.

Logged onto Fusion and now I only get the Windows screen with no icons or Start Button. I don't want to uninstall in fear of losing all of my work including Quickbooks!

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: This would be better on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Your virtual machines should not be touched by uninstalling the virtualisation software - you can even take a backup of the entire folder just to be sure.

However, do you have any problems with any other virtual machines? If so, this is most likely a problem with the virtualisation software and reinstalling should help.

If however, it is just with this virtual machine, it may be a problem that can not be repaired by reinstalling. I would recommend reinstalling Windows inside a new VM and try to map/mount the VMDK/Virtual hard drive and pull your Quickbooks data off of it.